# Calling Saved Powershell Script in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis, etl

I have created a Powershell script and saved it.  I want to be able to call it via a step in an SSIS package, which sends an email with a file attachment.  Attached is how the step looks in Process Task Editor

[image]

It says it has executed it, but I don't receive any email.  If I run the Powershell script manually, I do receive it.  If I take the ' out of the start and end of the file location, it won't execute at all.  Is there anything wrong with my settings?  I have set the policy on the machine to allow all scripts.

Comment: guess you need UNC path, not C:\. I am not sure of exact steps. Kindly refer google and read about UNC path specification

Comment: There's likely an error occurring that you're missing.  Try add some logging and error trapping to your script.  Powershell.exe does not always return a result code from an executed script that SSIS will see.  There's some detail about that [here](http://www.maxtblog.com/2011/09/creating-your-own-exitcode-in-powershell-and-use-it-in-ssis-package/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following arguments

```
-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "C:\SSIS Export\execute.ps1"
```

**Reference**

- [Run PowerShell scripts in SSIS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssis/2017/01/26/run-powershell-scripts-in-ssis/)